# Returning the file as a url in json format RestApi

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, api, multer

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hxqXCTVZYRJheXNi-WFz8K2ksLZiMNTY/view?usp=drivesdk

I am creating a restfull api in which user uploads and downloads some file from server.
I have a system in which user is uploading a file(lets say image) to the server. I have successfully done it by storing that file in the monogo db gridfs.

Now i want to create the get request in which user should get the file in a way that is mentioned in the above image.
I don't know how to send the file as a field. Which contains the url of the file.

If it is possible with any please do guide me. Thanks a lot.
I don't have enough reputation to post a pic so i have attached the drive link. thanks!

Comment: Sure, but the reason i didn't include any code is that i don't know how to download a file with rest in node. I just know the file-saver way to download a file

Answer (score 0):

okay, So after nearly a week i found the solution. which i was looking for.
i was trying to return the user display picture as a url which will be a seperate endpoint for our api. so you can easily get the image through that url.

so what i did was that i created a route for authentication purposes in which i am getting the full url form the request containing the file name as well. the authentiation method handles the authentication system which will authenticate the user and then pass the user id to the downloadimage method along with full url which will just query the data base for the user and the assign the dp(display picture) property the url to the image which will have the complete endpoint as well as the name of file as well. i have also attached the function which handles the image url later on.

```
async function downloadImage(id, fullUrl) {
  let comUrl;
  let user = await User.findById(id).select('-hash');

  // console.log(user);
  if (user.dp) {

    comUrl = fullUrl + user.dp


  }

 function authenticate(req, res, next) {
 var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host');
    let imageurl = await downloadImage(user.id, fullUrl);
        if (imageurl) {
          console.log(imageurl)
          userWithoutHash.dp = imageurl;

        }
}

router.get('/file/:filename', (req, res) => {

    gfs.model.readById(new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.filename), (err, file) => {

        console.log(file)
      // Check if file
      if (!file || file.length === 0) {
        return res.status(404)  .json({
          err: 'No file exists'
        });
      }
      const { Readable } = require('stream');
      // Check if image
      const stream = new Readable();
      stream.push(file);
      stream.push(null);

        stream.pipe(res);



    });
  });
```

output: will be like this

```
 { "dp": "http://localhost:4000/file/5cc0905839355d013c040794"}
```

I Hop i answer the above question if any confusion or any one needs help with this let me know thanks!.